# Как правильно пишется?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли выражение: "соблюдение указанного порядка не ОБУСЛОВЛЕНО объективной необходимостьью"? Или нужно другое слово употребить?

Answer (score 2):

Такое использование слова "обусловленно" вполне корректно.